# How to create javascript multidimentional array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps, spring-mvc

Here is my requirement

Need to create array like this.I'm use Spring mvc + ajax + jquery + google map 3.0
I'm get these values seperately as json response.

```
1. city name
2. long
3. lat
```

```
var markers = [['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856],['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052],['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507],['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187],['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302]];
```

how to create above loop with javascript array functions.may be records more than 20,30
is it 3D array.?

please help me to sort out this issue

thanks all

below show my script code and help me to modify that to get my target result

```
function jsonResponse(){
    var longitude=0;
    var latitude=0;
    var merchant='';
    var total =0;

    $.ajax({ 
        url: 'merchantsList.html', 
        dataType: 'json', 
        contentType: 'application/json',
        mimeType: 'application/json',
        success: function(data) {
            longitude=data.longitude;
            latitude=data.latitude;
            merchant=data.merchant;
            total = data.length;
        },
        error:function(data,status,er) { 
            alert("error: "+data+" status: "+status+" er:"+er);
        }
    });

    var markers = [['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856],['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052],
                   ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507],['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187],
                   ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302]];
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;
    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
            map: map
            });}
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(markers[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        };
    })(marker, i));

}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You want to create a nested array (note, there aren't any multidimensional arrays in JS), but then you provide exactly that in your code. What is it you are having problems with?

Comment: thanks dear Andy.below solutions helped me @ those are works :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some wild assumptions: var markers is sample data, and you want to replace that with what is returned by the ajax query; city name == merchant  in the ajax data.

If the data coming back from merchantsList.html has multiple merchant/long/lat items, you'll need to iterate over data and add each to the markers array.
That would be

```
var markers = [];

// ajax call start here..
    // ...
    success: function(data) {
        var i, item;
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            item = data[i];
            markers.push([item.merchant, item.longtitude, item.latitude]);
        }
    },
// ajax call end code here
```

Comment: Many many thanks Mr. MSpreij

Answer (score 1):

> Create multidimension array in javascript

```
var iMax = 20;
var jMax = 10;

var f = new Array();

for (i=0;i<iMax;i++) {

 f[i]=new Array();

 for (j=0;j<jMax;j++) {

  f[i][j]=0;

 }

}
```

Comment: all of your answers help me a lot.thanks dear Tamizh :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're talking about how do you iterate over your markers... You currently do this:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;
for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
        map: map
        });
}
```

but this won't work: `new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude)`. You need to get the lat and long from the current marker:

```
 position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]),
```